# sorting linked list of Hashmap based on their id key

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator

I'm having the HashMap stored in the Linked List need to sort them in the Descending order.Have given my code below

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Comparator;
            import java.util.HashMap;
            import java.util.LinkedList;

            public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>> list=new LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>>();

     HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id","2");
    map.put("code","200");
    HashMap<String,String> map2=new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("id","1");
    map2.put("code","100");
    HashMap<String,String> map3=new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("id","3");
    map3.put("code","300");
    list.add(map);
    list.add(map2);
    list.add(map3);
    System.out.println("List is::"+list);

    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(m -> Integer.parseInt(m.get("id"))));
    System.out.println("list after sorting is::"+list);


    }
}
```

I want a Linkedlist in Descending Order like below

```
            map 3,map, map 2
```

Comment: Have you tried something? And there are a lot of typos in your code

Comment: Descending order based on on what? You put 3,1,2 here... Where's your attempts at that?

Comment: Also, hashmaps aren't sorted. Linked lists aren't optimized to be either

Comment: In descending order base on what? values in the maps? then why are you using `HashMap` in the first place? make a class.

Comment: LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>> list=new LinkedList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  
  HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
 map.put("id","2");
 map.put("code","200");
 HashMap<String,String> map2=new HashMap<>();
 map2.put("id","1");
 map2.put("code","100");
 HashMap<String,String> map3=new HashMap<>();
 map3.put("id","3");
 map3.put("code","300");
 list.add(map);
 list.add(map2);
 list.add(map3);
 System.out.println("List is::"+list);
 
 list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(m -> Integer.parseInt(m.get("id"))));
 System.out.println("list after sorting is::"+list);

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code

Comment: Edit your post with your code

Comment: @Jose This question is about sorting a list, not a map

Comment: able to get the Ascending order but dont know for Descending order

Comment: Yeap didn't see the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap and specify comparator in it's constructor. It is what about Map. But if you want to sort a linked list of hashmaps, you can use Collections.sort(list, comparator).
But this is just brutal...

Answer (score 0):

> Comparator.comparingInt(m -> Integer.parseInt(m.get("id"))

You have to switch the order.

```
 list.sort((firstMap, secondMap) -> Integer.valueOf(secondMap.get("id"))
            .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(firstMap.get("id"))));
```